# Problems with $_POST["var"] in Yii Controller

Tags: javascript, php, json, post, yii

i am having problems with $_POST["var"] on controller. It seems to be empty. How can i receive the string being typed on my textFiled?

**View**

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript("jquery"); ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#hhmm").change(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                      url: "<?php echo CController::createUrl('reqTest01Loading'); ?>",
                                data: $(this).serialize(),
                                type: "post",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function(data) {
                                      if (data.status === 'failure') {
                                            $('#impatto').val('Error request failed.');
                                         } else {
                                                 $("#impatto").html(data.total);     
                                         } 

                                }
                        });
                        });

                });
                </script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function actionReqTest01Loading() {

    $result = array("total" => $_POST['hhmm'], "status"=>"OK");
            echo CJSON::encode($result);
}
```

**rules on Controller**

```
array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('reqTest01Loading','index','view','admin'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
```

[image: first of click impatto calcolo]
[image: after of click impatto calcolo]

thanks in advance

Comment: use CVarDumper::Dump($_POST,100,true); in your controller to see all the data being sent through ajax.

Comment: your are trying $_POST['hhmm'] which is wrong because ajax does not set html element`s id. You may try $_POST['data']

Comment: print_r($_POST) and check what its returning

Comment: i'm not having any response when use `CVarDumper::Dump($_POST,100,true);` or `print_r($_POST)` it's just blank. By the way changing hhmm into data there's not any response just: **{"total":null,"status":"OK"}**

Comment: try `var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you dont tell ajax call to send parameters.

Try:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo CController::createUrl('reqTest01Loading'); ?>",
       data: {data:$(this).serialize()},
       type: "post",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data) {
           if (data.status === 'failure') {
              $('#impatto').val('Error request failed.');
           } else {
              $("#impatto").html(data.total);     
           } 

        }
   });
```

And it controller:

```
public function actionReqTest01Loading() {
    // var_dump(Yii::app()->request->getPost('data'));
    $result = array("total" => Yii::app()->request->getPost('data'), "status"=>"OK");
    echo CJSON::encode($result);
}
```

Comment: Hi TNC, i updated the code like you say, even **Controller** looks like:

`public function actionReqTest01Loading() {
       
        var_dump(Yii::app()->request->getPost('data'));
        $result = array("total" => 60 + $_POST['hhmm'], "status"=>"OK");
        
        echo CJSON::encode($result);
}`

 `var_dump(Yii::app()->request->getPost('data'));` inhibits the ajax call

After commented that line i have added **60 + ** so in the view lets me see only 60 but don't sum **hhmm** is like there is not $_POST["hhmm"]

thanks again

Comment: You can get `$(this).serialize()` in `Yii::app()->request->getPost('data')`;
Check the value on  `$(this).serialize()`

Comment: The value in `$(this).serialize()` is null. How could this be possible??? Maybe i will try to implement a different solution with Autocomplete, i can not get it why this value is null.